Exclude interpolated rows where gap is bigger than a given theshhold
I have temperture data from different places. Recordings are usually made every hour but sometimes there are bigger gaps between two dates. So the data is like this:
df <- data.frame(date= lubridate::ymd_hms(c("2011-01-02 08:00:00", "2011-01-02 09:00:00", "2011-01-02 10:00:00", "2011-01-02 11:00:00", "2011-01-02 12:00:00",
                                        "2011-01-04 08:00:00", "2011-01-04 09:00:00", "2011-01-04 10:00:00", "2011-01-04 11:00:00", "2011-01-04 12:00:00",
                                        
                                        "2012-04-22 00:00:00", "2012-04-22 01:00:00", "2012-04-22 02:00:00", "2012-04-22 13:00:00", "2012-04-24 05:00:00",
                                        "2012-04-24 06:00:00", "2012-04-24 07:00:00", "2012-04-24 08:00:00", "2012-04-24 09:00:00", "2012-04-24 10:00:00")),
             id= rep(LETTERS[1:2], each= 10))
df$temp <- rnorm(nrow(df), 15, 5) + rep(c(1, 10), each= 10)

I interpolate the data and plot it. Something like this:
library(magrittr)
df_interpolated <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
  dplyr::reframe(date_interpolate_for= seq(min(date), max(date), by= "secs"),
                 temp_interpolated= approx(date, temp, xout= date_interpolate_for)$y,
                 id= unique(id))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data= df_interpolated, mapping= aes(date_interpolate_for, temp_interpolated), size= .5) +
  geom_point(data= df, mapping= aes(date, temp), col= "red") +
  facet_wrap(. ~ id, scales= "free_x") +
  theme_bw()


In the former plot, the black "line" shows the interpolated data and the red points the actual measured temperature. The problem is that there are those big gaps between two dates where the interpolation makes us think that the temperature changed from date x to date x+1 like a straight line. This is unplausible if the date gaps last days, months or even years. Therefore, I want to exclude rows from df_interpolated  if the gaps between the real dates in df are bigger than a choosen threshold. Lets say we pick a treshold of 12 hours, than the resulting data would look like that:
df_interpolated2 <- df_interpolated %>%
  dplyr::filter(id == "A" & date_interpolate_for <= lubridate::ymd_hms("2011-01-02 12:00:00") |
                  id == "A" & date_interpolate_for >= lubridate::ymd_hms("2011-01-04 08:00:00") |
                  id == "B" & date_interpolate_for <= lubridate::ymd_hms("2012-04-22 13:00:00") |
                  id == "B" & date_interpolate_for >= lubridate::ymd_hms("2012-04-24 05:00:00"))

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data= df_interpolated2, mapping= aes(date_interpolate_for, temp_interpolated), size= .5) +
  geom_point(data= df, mapping= aes(date, temp), col= "red") +
  facet_wrap(. ~ id, scales= "free_x") +
  theme_bw()


So what I have so far is df and df_interpolated, but how to exclude rows based on a choosen threshold in order to get df_interpolated2? In the code above, I did it by hand - how can I achieve this progmatically?

Create groups and connect according to groups.

@Friede The places are coded with the id variable. I am not sure how/ why I would create another grouping variable?

interaction()?

@Friede interaction() between dates per id? Can't figure it out. Our do you mean intersection?

One way is to create another grouping variable derived from the date differences exceeding your threshold.
threshold <- 12

df_interpolated <- df %>%
  mutate(keep=cumsum(c(1, diff(date))>threshold), .by=id) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(id, keep) %>%
  dplyr::reframe(date_interpolate_for=seq(min(date), max(date), by= "secs"),
                 temp_interpolated= approx(date, temp, xout= date_interpolate_for)$y,
                 id= unique(id))

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data= df_interpolated, mapping= aes(date_interpolate_for, temp_interpolated), size= .5) +
  geom_point(data= df, mapping= aes(date, temp), col= "red") +
  facet_wrap(. ~ id, scales= "free_x") +
  theme_bw()




No, cumsum is used to create the groups. Then add to id in the next group_by to limit the interpolation (interpolation won't succeed across groups, only within groups).
